# Parsing Excel-like Cell Range to Numeric Format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert Excel-like cell ranges into a numeric format in JavaScript. The format I am aiming for is `[rowStart, columnStart, rowEnd, columnEnd]`.

For example, a cell range like "A1:B3" should be converted to "1:1:3:2", and a range like "AA1:AAV5" should become "1:27:5:724".

I am struggling to come up with a way to convert the column letters to numbers, especially when the column range exceeds 'Z' and starts from 'AA', 'AB', and so on.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function parseCellRange(cellRange) {
    // Split the range into start and end
    let [startCell, endCell] = cellRange.split(':');
    
    // Split startCell and endCell into row and column
    let startColum = startCell.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    let startRow = startCell.match(/(\d+)/)[1];
    let endColumn = endCell.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    let endRow = endCell.match(/(\d+)/)[1];

    // Convert column letters to numbers
    // This is where I am stuck    

    // Generate new cell range format
    let newCellRange = [rowStart, columnStart, rowEnd, columnEnd] 
    
    return(newCellRange)
}

// Tests
parseCellRange("A1:B3"); // Should return [1, 1, 3, 2]
parseCellRange("AA1:AAV5"); // Should return [1, 27, 5, 724]
```

Comment: There is some inconsistency between the text and the code comments: the text wants the conversion to be to "1:1:3:2", but in code comments you have [1, 1, 3, 2]. I understand it is trivial to convert one to the other, but maybe you could update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a function to convert a series of letters to a number (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72383708/5459839)) and use one regex-replace operation to make the final conversion:

```js
function lettersToNumber(letters) {
    letters = letters.toLowerCase();
    const offset = "a".charCodeAt() - 1;
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        sum = sum * 26 + letters.charCodeAt(i) - offset;
    }
    return sum;
}

function parseCellRange(range) {
    return range.replace(/^([a-z]+)(\d+):([a-z]+)(\d+)$/gi, (_, c1, r1, c2, r2) =>
        `${r1}:${lettersToNumber(c1)}:${r2}:${lettersToNumber(c2)}`
    );
}

// Tests
console.log(parseCellRange("A1:B3")); // 1:1:3:2
console.log(parseCellRange("AA1:AAV5")); // 1:27:5:724
```

This returns the text version as you described at the top of your question. If you want arrays, like specified in your code comments, then use this version of `parseCellRange`:

```js
function lettersToNumber(letters) {
    letters = letters.toLowerCase();
    const offset = "a".charCodeAt() - 1;
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        sum = sum * 26 + letters.charCodeAt(i) - offset;
    }
    return sum;
}

function parseCellRange(range) {
    const [[, c1, r1, c2, r2]] = range.matchAll(/^([a-z]+)(\d+):([a-z]+)(\d+)$/gi);
    return [+r1, lettersToNumber(c1), +r2, lettersToNumber(c2)];
}

// Tests
console.log(parseCellRange("A1:B3")); // [1, 1, 3, 2]
console.log(parseCellRange("AA1:AAV5")); // [1, 27, 5, 724]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the column name as a 26-based number and then you want to convert it to a decimal number:

For example AAV, the equation is:

```
index(V) * 26^0 + index(A) * 26^1 + index(A) * 26^2
= (22 * 1) + (1 * 26) + (1 * 676) = 724
```

Here is a working solution:

```js
const ASCII_A = 'A'.charCodeAt();

function getColumnNumber(column) {
  let res = 0, power = 1;
  for (const letter of column.split("").reverse()) {
    const letterIndex = letter.charCodeAt() - ASCII_A + 1;
    res += power * letterIndex;
    power *= 26;
  }
  
  return res;
}

function parseCellRange(range) {
    // Split the range into start and end
    let [startCell, endCell] = range.split(':');
    
    // Split startCell and endCell into row and column
    let startColumn = startCell.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0];
    let startRow = +startCell.match(/(\d+)/)[1];
    let endColumn = endCell.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0];
    let endRow = +endCell.match(/(\d+)/)[1];

    // Convert column letters to numbers
    const startColumnNumber = getColumnNumber(startColumn);
    const endColumnNumber = getColumnNumber(endColumn);

    // Generate new cell range format
    let newCellRange = [startRow, startColumnNumber, endRow, endColumnNumber];
    
    return(newCellRange)
}

// Tests
console.log(parseCellRange("A1:B3")); // Should return [1, 1, 3, 2]
console.log(parseCellRange("AA1:AAV5")); // Should return [1, 27, 5, 724]
```

Answer (score 0):

I build this class that works with any letters array.

```
class LetterToNumber
{
  constructor(letters) {
    this._map = {};
    let j = 0;
    for (let l0 of letters) {
      this._map[l0] = ++j;
    }
    for (let l1 of letters) {
      for (let l2 of letters) {
        this._map[l1+l2] = ++j;
      }
    }
  }
  getNumber(key) {
    if (!this._map.hasOwnProperty(key))
      throw 'not found';
    return this._map[key];
  }
}

// usage
let letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
let ltn = new LetterToNumber(letters);
for (let key of ['A','AC','AA','ZS','FI']) {
  echo key +' = '+ ltn.getNumber(key);
}
```

Comment: Now what if you have a key with three letters, or four, or more?

Comment: Not found! Jokes apart, it seems that the question doesn't ask for this. Anyway, once you understand how the class is built, it's easy to generalize.