# Convert a number to Excel column letter

Tags: javascript, excel

This is a JavaScript "port" of the following questions, which ask the same thing about C# and Python, respectively:

- [How to convert a column number (e.g. 127) into an Excel column (e.g. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-e-g-127-into-an-excel-column-e-g-aa)
- [Convert a number to Excel’s base 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983939/convert-a-number-to-excel-s-base-26/)

> How do you convert a numerical number to an Excel column name <del>in C#</del> without using automation getting the value directly from Excel.
>
> Excel 2007 has a possible range of 1 to 16384, which is the number of columns that it supports. The resulting values should be in the form of excel column names, e.g. A, AA, AAA etc.

Comment: Would the linked duplicate work as an answer for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toExcelCol` and `fromExcelCol` from the following code:

```js
/** @param {number} n */
const divmodExcel = (n) => {
    const a = Math.floor(n / 26)
    const b = n % 26

    return b === 0 ? [a - 1, b + 26] : [a, b]
}

const uppercaseAlphas = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) =>
    String.fromCodePoint(i + 'A'.codePointAt(0)),
)

/** @param {number} n */
const toExcelCol = (n) => {
    const chars = []

    let d
    while (n > 0) {
        ;[n, d] = divmodExcel(n)
        chars.unshift(uppercaseAlphas[d - 1])
    }
    return chars.join('')
}

/** @param {string} str */
const fromExcelCol = (str) => [...str]
    .map((ch) => uppercaseAlphas.indexOf(ch))
    .reduce((n, i) => n * 26 + i + 1, 0)

console.log(`toExcelCol(702) => ${toExcelCol(702)}`) // ZZ
console.log(`toExcelCol(703) => ${toExcelCol(703)}`) // AAA
console.log(`fromExcelCol('ZZ') => ${fromExcelCol('ZZ')}`) // 702
console.log(`fromExcelCol('AAA') => ${fromExcelCol('AAA')}`) // 703
```

These are a port of [@poke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984697/convert-a-number-to-excel-s-base-26/) on the Python version.

Note that these operate in the 1-indexed world of Excel, such that `fromExcelCol('A')` gives `1`, not `0`.